# Make TODAY formula stop when checkbox is clicked

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm setting up a Google Sheet with a few columns to be filled for a certain request. So, I included a checkbox to be clicked at the end as a confirmation the request is done. My idea is to have an automated column called 'Request Date' automatically filled with the current date as soon as the Confirmation checkbox is clicked. However, can't use `TODAY()` formula once it's going to change the date every day. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately no. you can't stop `TODAY` on demand by any means without a script. but you could have a script which would print out the date if certain checkboxes were checked.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var aCell = e.source.getActiveCell(), col = aCell.getColumn(); 
  if(col == 5) { //number of column where you have a checkbox
    var adjacentCell = aCell.offset(0,1);
    var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
      "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    adjacentCell.setValue(newDate);
  }}
```

this will print date in column **F** if a checkbox in column **E** is checked

---

or perhaps like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (activeSheet.getName() == "Sheet1") {                   // SHEET NAME
    var aCell = e.source.getActiveCell(), col = aCell.getColumn();
    if (col == 12) {                                         // COLUMN WITH CHECKBOXES
      var dateCell = aCell.offset(0,1);                      // OFFSET ROWS, COLUMNS
      if (aCell.getValue() === true) {                       // VALUE OF CHECKED CHECKBOX
        var newDate = new Date();
        dateCell.setValue(newDate);
      } else {
        dateCell.setValue("");
      }}}}
```

Comment: This will run if *any* change is made to Column E - you could incorporate a check for `checkbox.isChecked()` to make sure it's only setting the date when the checkbox is ticked.

Comment: I'm not sure if `e` returns a checkbox option. Would it be easier to use
`e.value == "TRUE"` ?

Comment: @ADW you could get the row/col from `e.range` and get the checkbox using those. `e.value == "TRUE"` would work if the checkbox was set to TRUE/FALSE but as you can customize this it may fail if for example, it was set to Yes/No instead.

Comment: Trying to run via Google Apps Script ('Tools' and '<> Script Editor' from the horizontal menu in my google sheet, but as I try to run the script, it's giving the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")"

Comment: @ross pointed a very important thing. Can you just tell me where to include the checkbox.isChecked() in the script, please? Also, my spread sheet has many tabs, so I need to make it work for the tab(s) I want only, please. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: The script is working now @player0 THANK YOU very much. But, I still need to tweak the coding with the checkbox bit and include directions to run it on specific sheet(s) only. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: @EduardoOrdonez Use `if (col === 5 && aCell.isChecked() === true)` for your `if` statement to check if the checkbox is checked or not. There are plenty of examples of how to use `onEdit` triggers on certain sheets, just do a quick search online for that code.

Comment: @ross unfortunately it doesn't work = ( and also stops the date print. I'll have a look at the onEdit triggers you suggested though. Many thanks.

Comment: @EduardoOrdonez this script automatically uses a simple `onEdit` trigger because it is called `onEdit`.

Comment: @EduardoOrdonez just did some testing and you can actually just use `e.range.isChecked() === true` inside the `if` statement to make sure the box is checked.

Comment: Thanks @Ross I'm using the following script as per your guidance, but it still doesn't work for me.                                                                                              function onEdit(e) {
  var aCell = e.source.getActiveCell(), col = aCell.getColumn(); 
  if(col === 12 && e.range.isChecked() === true) { //number of column where you have a checkbox
    var adjacentCell = aCell.offset(0,1);
    var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
      "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    adjacentCell.setValue(newDate);
  }}

Comment: the only difference is the column I have my checkbox, which is column 12

Comment: Hi @player0, your effort is much appreciated, but unfortunately the second option does not work at all. The first script was closer I guess for it worked at least, although its logic was the problem for it's supposed to print a date when there was a ticked chekbox (true) only and not an empty checkbox. I think I'll end up moving to something easier like 'if' cell X === 'Done', then print today's date.